# Elastic search node does not join to cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

I have created elastic search cluster with 3 nodes , two master eligible nodes and one data node,
following are the .yml file configurations (commented settings are omitted)

**master_node**

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-148-generic x86_64)
#
# ======================== Elasticsearch Configuration =========================
#
# ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
#
cluster.name: silkstreet_cluster
#
# ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
#
node.name: master_node
node.master: true
#
# ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
#
# Path to log files:
#
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
#
# ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
# .....
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
#
network.host: 0.0.0.0
#
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when this node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
discovery.seed_hosts: ["master_node_ip","data_node_01_ip","data_node_02_ip"]
# Bootstrap the cluster using an initial set of master-eligible nodes:
#
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["master_node", "data_node_01"]
#
# ---------------------------------- Gateway -----------------------------------
#
# ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
#
```

**data_node_01**

```
# ======================== Elasticsearch Configuration =========================
# ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
#
cluster.name: silkstreet_cluster
#
# ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
#
node.name: data_node_01
node.data: true
#
# ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
#
# Path to log files:
#
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
#
# ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
#
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
#
network.host: 0.0.0.0
#
# Set a custom port for HTTP:
#
#http.port: 9200
#
# For more information, consult the network module documentation.
#
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when this node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
discovery.seed_hosts: ["master_node_ip","data_node_01_ip","data_node_02_ip"]
#
# Bootstrap the cluster using an initial set of master-eligible nodes:
#
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["master_node","data_node_01"]
#
# For more information, consult the discovery and cluster formation module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Gateway -----------------------------------
#
# ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
```

**data_node_02**

```
 ======================== Elasticsearch Configuration =========================
#
# ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
#
cluster.name: silkstreet_cluster
#
# ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
#
node.name: data_node_02
node.master: false
node.data: true
#
# ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
#
# Path to log files:
#
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
#
# ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
#
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
#
network.host: 0.0.0.0
#
# Set a custom port for HTTP:
#
#http.port: 9200
#
# For more information, consult the network module documentation.
#
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when this node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
discovery.seed_hosts: ["master_node_ip","data_node_01_ip","data_node_02_ip"]
#
# Bootstrap the cluster using an initial set of master-eligible nodes:
#
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["master_node_ip", "data_node_01_ip"]
#
# For more information, consult the discovery and cluster formation module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Gateway -----------------------------------
#
# ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
#
```

Issue is all nodes not create cluster ,

master node and data node 02 are forming one cluster and , data node 01 create one individual cluster separately.

Do i miss anything in the .yml configuration ?

invoking http://(master_node_ip):9200/_cluster/state?pretty

returning

[image]

and invoking cluster api on data_node_01 
returns

[image]

Can any one help on this ?

Comment: can you remove the comments from `.yml` file and just provide the final key values pairs, so that its easy for SO users to read and help.

Answer (score 0):

Split brain Problem in Elastic search

https://qbox.io/blog/split-brain-problem-elasticsearch

@Roshan

update :

Your problem is with `discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes:`
You did'nt set that value  , Default is 1 ,

in your case master eligible nodes are 2 and only one node is needed to elect master nodes ,

master_node and data_node_01 will themselves assign as master nodes
hence split brain

Comment: Hi , i want know one thing in here , data_node_01 is data node as well as it is eligible  for  master node , because we haven't mentioned `node.master=false` , master_node also eligible for master node , How the cluster elect one , to be a master node?

Comment: Hi @Roshan 
The election procedure is clearly explained in the above link ,

also updated the answer

Comment: Thank you , for the mentioned article , i have followed it.

Comment: I have added `discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2` to all three .yml but still have Split brain Problem.